# Problem with IF conditional with None variable in dataframe [Python]

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement, nonetype

I have a problem with the None type into a df and I wanted to take the data if the x is not None, as follows:

```
x = None
y = 5

if x is not None:
    y = x
```

When is not None y = 5, but if:

```
x = 9
y = 5

if x is not None:
    y = x
```

And y = 9.

But when I do this in a df:

```
Data = {'x': 100,'y': None}  
df = pd.DataFrame(Data, columns= ['x','y', index=[0])

if df.loc[0, 'y'] is not None:
     df.loc[0, 'x'] = df.loc[0, 'y']
```

df.loc[0, 'x'] = nan

Why 'nan' if it should be 100?

Comment: When I use your code to create `df`, the value at `df.loc[0, 'y']` is `np.nan` and not `None`. If you want to keep the data as `None`, try `df = pd.DataFrame(Data, index=[0])`

Comment: Thank you @not_speshal that'd do it!

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between `None` and `nan`. When you create a dataframe from your data, `None` becomes `nan`. This is because column format is `float` and `None` is not an acceptable value for that type. So `pandas` does the implicit conversion. This should work.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Data = {'x': 100,'y': None}  
df = pd.DataFrame(Data, columns= ['x','y'], index=[0])

if df.loc[0, 'y'] is not np.nan:
     df.loc[0, 'x'] = df.loc[0, 'y']
```

It is also possible to keep your original logic, if you prevent conversion of `None`->`nan` by explicitly specifying `object` as `dtype`, which does have `None`

```py
import pandas as pd

Data = {'x': [100],'y': [None]}  
df = pd.DataFrame(Data, columns= ['x','y'], index=[0], dtype=object)

if df.loc[0, 'y'] is not None:
     df.loc[0, 'x'] = df.loc[0, 'y']
```